# Theoretical: binding to SQL Views

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, mvvm

I have a view which is bound to a view model that represents an object model, in DB (it's defined with `[Table(Name = "...")]` attribute). The view model has `EntitySet`s to allow the view to show data from linked tables(they used as sources for DataGrids). I want to add a `DataGrid` that will be bound to a SQL View (which composed of partial data from several tables). It should show only related to the main record from the view model rows, which in case of tables is possible through `EntitySet`s. How this should be implemented?

In my investigation I've tried to see how Object Relational Designer (O/R Designer) - the DBML Designer in VS 2012 does it's part and noticed that it doesn't include implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` when it creates classes for SQL views. Is there any special reason for that or it just because the fields shouldn't be updated (since it's view)?

Should I treat the view the same way as a table, or something should be different? I assume that at least the binding should be defined with `OneWay` mode. And how the relationship to the current record in main view should be defined?

Comment: Wall of text, and no code. Do you really think anyone will read this? at least use some punctuation for God's sake.

Comment: @HighCore that's why it's theoretical, the question is simple and is located in last paragraph. Everything before is just "wall of text" to explain what do I mean. Sorry for that... And now thanks to jessehouwing I know how to do the inline mark up, never succeed in that before...